# nullPointerException when running app on lower Android versions

Tags: java, android

My app is running fine on my Samsung Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.3 but when I try to run it on devices with older version (Android 2.3.6 to be exact) it crashes when a certain activity should be loaded.

```
12-08 16:50:10.873: E/AndroidRuntime(10200): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-08 16:50:10.873: E/AndroidRuntime(10200):    at si.dvanadva.evanturist.PlaceItemActivity.onCreate(PlaceItemActivity.java:259)
```

this is the logcat error that I get when I lunch the activity. This is the line 259 in class file:

```
reklamniBannerImgView.setOnClickListener(this);
```

But there's nothing wrong with it! I have a few other onClickListeners that are set exactly the same way and it works good. Here's how I do it:

ImageButton xml code:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view_reklamni_banner"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_view_item_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/image_view_item_image_height"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            />
```

Getting it in java:

```
//global variable
private ImageView reklamniBannerImgView;

//this is in onCreate
reklamniBannerImgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view_reklamni_banner);
reklamniBannerImgView.setOnClickListener(this);
```

And then I have a switch statement to handle the click:

```
case R.id.image_view_reklamni_banner:
        Intent spletnaStranTrbovlje = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        spletnaStranTrbovlje.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.trbovlje.si/"));
        startActivity(spletnaStranTrbovlje);
        break;
```

It all works good on higher versions of Android but when I run it on a device with Android version 2.3.6 it crashes before the activity with this button is even loaded. **Before I even press the button!**

I'm really confused because nothing like this happened before. Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: do you set the same layout in which you have imageview to the activity?

Comment: @Raghunandan yes, I do

Comment: post the xml that you set to the activity and the activity onCreate full

Comment: @Raghunandan I already have my issue resolved, check the accepted answer :) thanks for you help anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have two different layout folders one for v11> and for v11< (for example) and layout for the low api levels doesn't contain your ImageView

Comment: No, I actuallyy have only one layout folder, nothing else

Comment: Wait, no, you were right! I do only have one layout folder but I have two different XML files for the same activity, one for the older versions and one for the newer versions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it in onWindowFocusChanged(boolean) of your activity